# Change Wordpress Timber Template locations

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, twig

I need to overwrite the page template locations for Woocommerce using timber Wordpress.

All page Templates are stored in the theme root folder and i want to move the woocommerce files 
(like **single-product.php**) to a custom subfolder.

The folder should be in the same theme (my-theme/custom/single-product.php)

I have read around on google but haven't been able to find a definitive answer.
Thanks

Comment: You want to use [Wordpress Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Comment: @Rene Korss thanks for response, the custom template folder should be in the same theme directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
/* functions.php */
Timber::$dirname = array( 'templates', 'templates/woo-templates');
```

http://timber.github.io/timber/#changing-the-default-folder-for-twig-files

The code above will first look in `templates` and then in the `woo-templates` sub directory for .twig templates

Comment: Is there anyway to set a wild card? For example: `Timber::$dirname = array( 'templates', 'templates/components/*');` I wonder if anyone found a way to do something similar?

Comment: Sorry @csalmeida I moved to a different stack and havent done any Twig or WP in a long time.